# How to access Magento bitnami on GCP database and run SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, magento, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

How to access Magento bitnami on GCP database and run SQL statements. I do not know where and how to connect to the Magento bitnami on GCP database and run SQL statements

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here.

You have different options to run those SQL commands:

- Access the instance using a SSH connection and connect to MySQL using the command line. You will need to configure the SSH key in the Google Console in case you don't have a valid one. Then, you can access MySQL by running this command

  ```
  mysql -u root -p bitnami_magento
  ```
- Create a SSH tunnel to access phpMyAdmin: We configure phpMyAdmin to only be accessible using a local connection. The SSH tunnel will allow you access /phpmyadmin and you could run the SQL commands there.

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/magento/administration/access-phpmyadmin/

If you need more information about how SSH works and how to access the instance, please check our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/get-started/connect-ssh/